# HTTP Status NIL using both URLSession and AlamoFire. Error Code=303 and NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask

Tags: swift, auth0, urlsession, general-network-error

**What's Expected:**

- Response with status code 200 and a JSON body with auth token etc.

**What's Happening:**

- A device will (randomly?) no longer make the login call to auth0 successfully.
- HTTP status code, response data will all be nil values.
  -Other devices running the same app branch, same wifi network are able to make the call with no issue. Then after some time, generally 1-2 days the problem phone will no longer have any trouble making the call and will continue on as before the issue started.
- Throws error Code 303 (CFNetworkErrors.cfErrorHTTPParseFailure) in logs. Apple docs say it's a failure to parse the response from the server. I believe it's because the response data is null.

**App Version:**

- This issue has shown up so far on iOS devices running 14.6 or higher.

**Testing:**

- Used both an AlamoFire based and URLSession based network call and both can have the issue. The example code below is using the URLSession instead of the AlamoFire, but switching does not seem to have an effect on stopping devices from being able to develop the issue.
- Changing from WiFi to Celluar internet has no effect, changing to another WiFi network has no effect either.
- Deleting the App and reinstalling has no effect.
- Because I have not figured out what triggers the issue I have only got my hands on a device with the issue a few times before it resolved itself and there was nothing to test.
- I have managed to save some logs (print statements and some Firebase Analytics console messages). The segments I think are useful are pasted below.

**Network call Code:**

```
func makeNetworkCall(url: String, method: HTTPMethod = .get, parameters: Parameters? = nil, headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil, timeout: Double, completion: @escaping (DefaultURLRequestReturnModel) -> Void ) {
        
        logger.debug("makingCall with: url= _\(url)_ method= _\(method)_, param= _\(parameters)_, headers= _\(headers)_")
        
        var urlRequest: URLRequest?
        var hasReturned: Bool = false
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + timeout, execute: {
            if !hasReturned {
                completion(DefaultURLRequestReturnModel(isSuccess: false, statusCode: ErrorCodes.timeoutError.rawValue, action: .failure, dataResponse: nil))
            }
        })
        
        do {
            urlRequest = try URLRequest(url: url, method: method, headers: headers)
            
            if let parameters = parameters {
                urlRequest?.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)
            }
        } catch {
            completion(DefaultURLRequestReturnModel(isSuccess: false, statusCode: ErrorCodes.encodeError.rawValue, action: .failure, dataResponse: nil))
            return
        }
        
        // Unwrap the optional urlRequest to confirm its != nil
        guard var safeURLRequest = urlRequest else {
            
            completion(DefaultURLRequestReturnModel(isSuccess: false, statusCode: ErrorCodes.encodeError.rawValue, action: .failure, dataResponse: nil))
            return
        }
        
        if safeURLRequest.httpBody != nil {
            safeURLRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        }
        
        let session = URLSession.shared

        logger.debug("before session.dataTask for url \(safeURLRequest.url)")
        let task = session.dataTask(with: safeURLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
            
            logger.debug("url session completion for safeURLRequest.url _\(safeURLRequest.url)_, response= _\(response)_, error= _\(error.debugDescription)_, data= _\(data)_")
            
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                
                logger.debug("url session completion for URL \(safeURLRequest.url): status \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                
                switch httpResponse.statusCode {
                    case 200, 204:
                        let defaultDataResponse = DefaultDataResponse(request: safeURLRequest, response: httpResponse, data: data, error: error)
                        completion(DefaultURLRequestReturnModel(isSuccess: true, statusCode: httpResponse.statusCode, action: httpResponse.statusCode == 200 ? .success : .successEmpty, dataResponse: defaultDataResponse))
                    default:
                        logger.debug("ON ERROR")
                        completion(DefaultURLRequestReturnModel(isSuccess: false, statusCode: httpResponse.statusCode, action: httpResponse.statusCode == 401 ? .authError : .failure, dataResponse: nil))
                }
            } else {
                // This is Trigged in the error logs
                logger.debug("url session completion for URL \(safeURLRequest.url): response = \(response) __ can't be cast to HTTPURLResponse")
                if NetworkManager.isConnectedToInternet() { logger.networkNilEvent() }
                completion(DefaultURLRequestReturnModel(isSuccess: false, statusCode: ErrorCodes.noResponseError.rawValue, action: .failure, dataResponse: nil))
            }
            
            hasReturned = true
            
        })

        task.resume()
        
    }
```

**Console Logs From A Problem Device:**

> debug: url session completion for safeURLRequest.url
> *Optional(https://cpht.auth0.com/oauth/ro)*, response= *nil*, error= _Optional(Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask
> .<9>,
> _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<CFData 0x28375a080 [0x1f9151860]>{length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes =
> 0x100201bb6810b8f80000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2205,
> *NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
> "LocalDataTask .<9>" )})*, data= *nil* debug: url session completion for URL
> Optional(https://cpht.auth0.com/oauth/ro): response = nil __ can't be
> cast to HTTPURLResponse

**Firebase Analytics Logs From A Problem Device:**

- I have replaced the IP Addresses from something like 100.0.0.0:443 to IP:443 in the following logs.
- App name has been changed to MyAppName

2021-08-12 16:59:51.615734-0500 MyAppName[4586:1910198] [] nw_protocol_instance_access_flow_state [C13.2.1:2] Failed to find flow 1090aae88
2021-08-12 16:59:51.615828-0500 MyAppName[4586:1910198] [] nw_protocol_instance_access_flow_state [C13.2.1:2] Failed to find flow 1090aae88
2021-08-12 16:59:51.624933-0500 MyAppName[4586:1910198] [] nw_protocol_instance_access_flow_state [C13.2.1:2] Failed to find flow 1090aae88
2021-08-12 16:59:51.625051-0500 MyAppName[4586:1910198] [] nw_protocol_instance_access_flow_state [C13.2.1:2] Failed to find flow 1090aae88
2021-08-12 16:59:51.625570-0500 MyAppName[4586:1910198] [] nw_protocol_instance_access_flow_state [C13.2.1:2] Failed to find flow 1090aae88
2021-08-12 16:59:51.625716-0500 MyAppName[4586:1910198] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_read_handler [C14 IP:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for read_timeout failed
2021-08-12 16:59:51.625773-0500 MyAppName[4586:1910198] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_write_handler [C14 IP:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for write_timeout failed
2021-08-12 16:59:51.625828-0500 MyAppName[4586:1910198] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_keepalive_handler [C14 IP:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for keepalive failed
2021-08-12 16:59:51.626028-0500 MyAppName[4586:1910198] [] nw_protocol_instance_access_flow_state [C13.2.1:2] Failed to find flow 1090aae88
2021-08-12 16:59:51.626859-0500 MyAppName[4586:1910198] [] nw_protocol_instance_access_flow_state [C13.2.1:2] Failed to find flow 10909f7c8
2021-08-12 16:59:51.627061-0500 MyAppName[4586:1910198] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_read_handler [C13.2.1 IP:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for read_timeout failed
2021-08-12 16:59:51.627118-0500 MyAppName[4586:1910198] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_write_handler [C13.2.1 IP:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for write_timeout failed
2021-08-12 16:59:51.627257-0500 MyAppName[4586:1910198] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_keepalive_handler [C13.2.1 IP:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for keepalive failed
2021-08-12 16:59:51.641425-0500 MyAppName[4586:1909925] [] nw_protocol_instance_access_flow_state [C13.2.1:2] Failed to find flow 1090aae88
2021-08-12 16:59:51.647736-0500 MyAppName[4586:1909925] Task .<9> HTTP load failed, 529/0 bytes (error code: 303 [4:-2205])
2021-08-12 16:59:51.648181-0500 MyAppName[4586:1909923] Task .<9> finished with error [303] Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask .<9>, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<CFData 0x28375a080 [0x1f9151860]>{length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes = 0x100201bb6810b8f80000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2205, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
"LocalDataTask .<9>"
)}
2021-08-12 16:59:51.648326-0500 MyAppName[4586:1909925] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_unregister_context [C13.2.1 IP:443 failed channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] Cannot unregister after flow table is released
2021-08-12 16:59:51.648393-0500 MyAppName[4586:1909925] [h3connection] 0x1099d1a18 13 closed with peer error 258
2021-08-12 16:59:51.648500-0500 MyAppName[4586:1909925] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_add_write_request [C13.2.1 IP:443 failed channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] Cannot send after flow table is released
2021-08-12 16:59:51.648625-0500 MyAppName[4586:1909925] [connection] nw_write_request_report [C13] Send failed with error "Socket is not connected"

Thank you for any of your ideas on fixing this issue!

Comment: just to confirm it: you are using _URLSession.shared_ when the issue occurs, and didn't change it for sake of the example? Can you also please clarify, where you get HTTPStatusCode as nil, and where you get ErrorCode 303?

Comment: For the interested readers: Code 303 means `CFNetworkErrors.cfErrorHTTPParseFailure` ... hm

Comment: I fear, you have to dig a little bit deeper to find a clue of the cause of the issue: [Debugging HTTPS Problems with CFNetwork Diagnostic Logging](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/debugging_https_problems_with_cfnetwork_diagnostic_logging)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I will edit the question, your right the 303 error is the apple CFNetwork Error, not an HTTP Error. I didn't know about CFNetwork Diagnostics Logger so I will look into that the next time I get my hands on a device with the issue. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: Yes, it's rather a disconnected connection than a redirect issue. ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Gotcha, anything you think I should try next time I get a device with the issue? Other than setting up the CFNetwork Diagnostics of course :)

Comment: And yes you are correct I was using `URLSession.shared` when the issue started happening and during logging etc. I don't think there was a version of the app using anything other `URLSession.shared`

Comment: You can even dig a level deeper: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/recording_a_packet_trace. Hope, you don't have to ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I will take a look into setting that up as well in preparation for the next device that comes my way. I appreciate your help and look forward to finding the solution to this problem!

Comment: I can confirm this issue to 100% what you described. We have out of nowhere customers (currently only in the us) who cant connect to the application with a 303 error. All other customers and the development team has no problems at all. We are very confused about this. Would love to hear a explanation for this mess

Comment: Never ended up finding a solution. Ended up proxying the network request through our server. So instead of iPhone -> Endpoint we changed it to iPhone -> Our Server -> Endpoint. Didn't figure out what caused the iPhones to not work but running it thru the server solved the problem and allowed us to progress.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issuie that you described. In our case, one of our custom request headers exceeded the max header size limit of the webserver. Nginx has a max header size around 8kb and will return a 413 error to the client if you exceed this limit. for whatever reason, the ios app will not parse this response and throw a 303 error. After we increased the http2_max_header_size to 32kb, it worked.

Comment: I did not get a chance to properly try this out before we switched how we called the endpoint. Switched from  iPhone -> Endpoint to adding in our server as proxy iPhone -> Our Server -> Endpoint. This solved the issue and since I had already burned over a week of time I never went back to find why the iPhone was having the issue.

Comment: i burned three weeks in this error.